# Adding Git Bash to Windows 10 Address Bar

Tags: bash, windows-explorer, git

I recently learned that **cmd** and **powershell** can be started from the address bar in the Windows File Explorer, which will then start a shell in that specific location.

I am now wondering if there's a way to expand this functionality by adding **Git Bash** to the address bar? I know that it can be added to the dropdown menu that shows 'up'? when using Right-Click, but I don't know how to add it to the address bar or if it can be done.

Thank you :)

---

Update. After adding the **Git Bash** executable to **PATH** it worked as I wanted it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every program or file can be launched via the address-bar of Windows Explorer,
the same as when entering the command in the Run box.

No special action is required, just enter the program's executable in the
address-bar with parameters.

But it might be easier to use the Run box
(<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>).

Comment: My mistake was that I hadn't added the executable to PATH - worked perfectly afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

To piggyback off the update, I was able to get it to work for me by adding `C:\Program Files\Git\bin`[that's where I installed git for windows, YMMV] to my user environment Path variable, then signing out and signing back in. The bin contains bash.exe, git.exe, and sh.exe.